# Cloudera Search (Solr) error - SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath

Tags: search, solr, cloudera, solrcloud

I am following the tutorial given by Cloudera in this page - [Preparing to Index Data with Cloudera Search](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/search_data_index_prepare.html). I was almost successful, but in the end when I try to index the sample data using batch mapreducer, I am getting the below error

`java.lang.Exception: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineRuntimeException: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/usr/lib/solr/file:/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/1494416503755/0c48826c-2ae0-4549-91a3-88807f5c6153.solr.zip/conf'
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:549)
Caused by: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineRuntimeException: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/usr/lib/solr/file:/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/1494416503755/0c48826c-2ae0-4549-91a3-88807f5c6153.solr.zip/conf'
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.solr.SolrLocator.getIndexSchema(SolrLocator.java:209)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.morphline.MorphlineMapRunner.<init>(MorphlineMapRunner.java:141)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.morphline.MorphlineMapper.setup(MorphlineMapper.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/usr/lib/solr/file:/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/1494416503755/0c48826c-2ae0-4549-91a3-88807f5c6153.solr.zip/conf'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:362)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:308)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:117)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:87)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:167)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.solr.SolrLocator.getIndexSchema(SolrLocator.java:201)
        ... 11 more`

I tried giving `--solr-home-dir` parameter also (pointing to `conf/solrconfig.xml`). But it didn't work. The final command that I run is in this page - [Using MapReduce Batch Indexing with Cloudera Search](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/search_batch_index_use_mapreduce.html).

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing `conf.cloudera.hdfs` with `conf.cloudera.yarn` in the final command, the error was gone. Hope it helps someone.